# Splitting up vector elements into separate lines in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'd like to separate a vector elements into separate lines when I render it in a modal dialog box using shinyalert. Here's an example:

```
a<- c("Question a", "Question b", "Question c", "Question d")

library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyalert(
    title = "Hello",
    text = a,
    size = "s", 
    closeOnEsc = TRUE,
    closeOnClickOutside = FALSE,
    html = FALSE,
    type = "success",
    showConfirmButton = TRUE,
    showCancelButton = FALSE,
    confirmButtonText = "OK",
    confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
    timer = 0,
    imageUrl = "",
    animation = TRUE
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I"m assuming I'll need to use HTML tags and possible paste0. I'd like the box to look something like this where:

```
1) Question a

2) Question b

3) Question c

4) Question d
```

with a space between questions and a numbering to make it look a bit more tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
a<- c("Question a", "Question b", "Question c", "Question d")

library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyalert(
    title = "Hello",
    text = paste0(1:4, ") ", a, collapse="\n"),
    closeOnEsc = TRUE,
    closeOnClickOutside = FALSE,
    html = FALSE,
    type = "success",
    showConfirmButton = TRUE,
    showCancelButton = FALSE,
    confirmButtonText = "OK",
    confirmButtonCol = "#AEDEF4",
    timer = 0,
    imageUrl = "",
    animation = TRUE
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Just collapse the vector using paste and specify "\n" (lineskip) between each collapsed element.